# Бонус - точный синоним

Tags: синонимы

Однажды меня спросили, что такое "бонус", и я несколько нависла над ответом. Я-то понимаю, что это такое, но для меня бонус - это бонус. А вот объяснить по-русски, что это такое, и найти точный синоним не получилось.
Может быть, вы поможете? Есть ли какой-то синоним слову "бонус"? Приз - не то. Награда - тоже. Сюрприз - тоже нет. "Приятный довесок"?)))))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это не всегда о деньгах (бывает "натурой"), хотя чаще поминают это слово как "премиальные выплаты" в премиальной системе оплаты труда. Более широкий смысл - "поощрение", нечто дополнительное к чему-то за что-то. Задолго до появления слова в русской прессе можно было увидеть англоязычную надпись на упаковке некоторых товаров. Напр. дополнительный фрагмент на компакт-диске /bonus track/, побуждающий купить именно его, а не стандартное издание того же альбома; в других случаях - дополнительное количество продукта в случае его покупки в большем количестве и т.п.

Comment: Да, согласен с вами: поощрение - наиболее широкий смысл.

Comment: Спасибо! Да, пожалуй, соглашусь, что это самый удачный синоним.

Answer (score 2):

Обратимся к словарям. БОНУС (от лат. bonus - хороший) - дополнительное вознаграждение. Это может быть премия, дополнительная скидка, добавочный дивиденд и т.п. Английский термин "bonus" употребляется также в словосочетаниях, означающих различные надбавки, напр, за выслугу лет, за сверхурочное время, на иждивенцев.***( Юридический словарь)***.
БОНУС
    (от лат. bonus - добрый, хороший)
    1) дополнительное вознаграждение, поощрение, надбавка к выплате, премия;
    2) дополнительная скидка со стоимости (цены) товара, предоставляемая продавцом в соответствии с условиями договора о купле-продаже или постоянным покупателям.***(Райзберг Б.А., Лозовский Л.Ш., Стародубцева Е.Б.. Современный экономический словарь. — 2-е изд., испр. М.: ИНФРА-М. 479 с.. 1999. )***
***Исходя из этого можно предложить следующие синонимы: вознаграждение, скидка, премия, поощрение.***

Answer (score 0):

Почему же "приз" не то? Самое то.

Answer (score 0):

Для меня бонус - это надбавка.

Но если в словарях два значения, то должно быть и  два ряда синонимов, одним самым точным не обойтись: вознаграждение (поощрение) и скидка  -  всё-таки разные значения.

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку слово происходит от латинского языка и означает: 
добрый, хороший, его (слово "бонус"), можно отнести и к вознаграждению, и к скидке, и к иному поощрению

Answer (score 0):

Народ, я конечно, соглашусь, что поощрение (вариант принятого ответа), это один из правильных смыслов, но не стоит забывать, что вы рассматриваете перевод этого слова не во всех возможных смыслах.
Например, в различного рода играх, есть такое понятие, как *Bonus from "something"*, куда совершенно не вяжется поощрение.

Простой пример. Миры, построенные на своде правил настольных игр Dungeon&Dragons, которые легли в основу практически всех компьютерных игр в жанре Role-Playing Game имеют такую характеристику как Maximum statistics bonus.

Данную характеристику можно и нужно переводить как Максимальная прибавка к параметру, а никак не поощрение.

Слово **прибавка** также прекрасно подходит к любому другому значению, приведенному в принятом ответе: Бонус-трек - прибавленная (в значении дополнительная) звуковая дорожка, прибавленное (в том же значении дополнительное) количество продукта, также прибавка к выплате в виде премии и в принципе во всех возможных других вариантах, к которым можно прикрутить слово бонус.

Comment: Купил чайник, и, как водится в этой сети магазинов, к нему «прикрутили» в качестве бонуса бутылку игристого. Можно ли прибавкой считать непрофильный (относительно основного) продукт? Может быть это  «Максимальная прибавка к параметру»?

Comment: А что не так: бесплатная прибавка к чайнику - бутылка игристого. Прибавка одного предмета ко второму. Или для тебя это поощрение? Купил чайник, тебя поощрили бутылкой... Ну хоть не по голове поощрили =)
Слово прибавка означает что-либо дополнительное, разве не так? Бутылка является дополнением в данном случае к чайнику. Я не вижу здесь нарушения логической цепи.

Comment: И чтоб не быть голословным выдержка из Большого толкового словаря:
В прибавку, в зн. нареч. Разг. Сверх чего-л., вдобавок.
Бонус - это всегда сверх чего-либо, вдобавок. В том числе и Ваша бутылка игристого.

Comment: Так определиться надо! Дополнением к чайнику может быть упаковка чая, тогда это — бонус. Механическая «Прибавка одного предмета ко второму» неразумна и вредна. Любителю чая не следует предлагать алкоголь. P.S. Не следует обращаться никаким образом к комментирующему Ответ, чтобы не попасть в неудобную ситуацию. Говорим только по теме Вопроса.

Comment: Ерунда какая-то. В рпг D&D играл много и охотно, характеристики **названной именно так** не встречал. Да шут бы с ней. Смысл понятен, что-то там про лимит на бесплатные плюшки. Но как это сказывается на переводе самого слова *бонус*? Увеличение, добавка, дополнительный стимул, подарок  - да масса вариантов перевода. Один другому не противоречит. Никто ж не сказал, что ищут **одно слово**. *Наоборот, сошлись во мнении, что единого, универсального синонима слову бонус не существует. * О чем спор?

Answer (score 0):

Бонус — подарок как благодарность, овеществлённое «спасибо» за покупку.